# Android test case: Check if a line is drawn on the canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, robotium

For an Android application I have a test case that checks if a line is actually drawn when a button is pressed. I use Robotium to press the button but can't find a way to check if the line is actually drawn on the canvas.